# The jar file has not source attachment "eclipse"

Tags: eclipse, jackson

I am working in an eclipse and when trying to incorporate the library "jackson-all-1.9.0.jar" does not recognize it.
I tried to put here the path "C: \ Program Files \ Java \ jdk1.8.0_161.src.zip" but it did not help. I would like to know if someone can give me a hand with this.

Try to create a new project with Maven but the result was the same

[image: Problem]

Comment: The summary and problem image don't seem to be related.

Answer (score 0):

Mavenise your current Java project and try adding below dependency in POM.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hello, I have done everything and I have adapted the code to pom.xml in a new project and the result remains the same, when executing it says "the ObjectMapper class has not been found"

Comment: @MauroGarcia image of error that you are getting after migrating to maven, please